# How to manually set colours to a categorical variables using ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

This is my sample data:

```
table1
   xaxis    yaxis                  ae        work
1      5    35736 Attending_Education     Working
2      6    72286 Attending_Education     Working
3      7   133316 Attending_Education     Working
4      8   252520 Attending_Education     Working
5      9   228964 Attending_Education     Working
6     10   504676 Attending_Education     Working
```

This is the code I had used.

```
p<-ggplot(table1,aes(x=table1$xaxis,y=table1$yaxis))

Economic_Activity<-factor(table1$work)
Education_Status<-factor(table1$ae)

p<-p+geom_point(aes(colour=Education_Status,shape=Economic_Activity),size=4)
p+xlab("Population Ages")+ylab("Attending Education Institutions Count")+ggtitle("Attending Educational Institutions by Economic Activity Status :: INDIA 2001")
```

This is the output I got.
[image]

I wish to do two things in this graph.

1. I wish to set color manually to these categorical variables (Attending_Education\Not_AE). For example. Dark Green color for Attending_Education and red color for Not_AE.
2. In the legend of economic activity, I don't need black color for working\not_working category. I need the Dark green and red color.

I am new to R. I had tried palette() too found @ below link. but nothing seems to work
[How to assign specfic colours to specifc categorical variables in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874240/how-to-assign-specfic-colours-to-specifc-categorical-variables-in-r)

Note: please look at my requirements.

```css
 Categories           Attending_Education           Not_AE
Working     Green color\Round Shape     Red Color\Round shape
Not_Working Green color\Triangle Shape  Red Color\Triangle shape
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanking u all.

Answer (score 5):

For your first question, you need to use `scale_colour_manual`:

```
p +
  xlab("Population Ages") +
  ylab("Attending Education Institutions Count") +
  ggtitle("Attending Educational Institutions by Economic Activity Status :: INDIA 2001") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Attending_Education" = "dark green", "Not_AE" = "red"))
```

For your second, I'm not clear what you want. Economic activity is represented as shape, not colour. So what would be the meaning of having dark green/red colours within that legend?

Comment: For first question i got the answer from Nick Kennedy. Thanking you.

Comment: For Second question, For two diffrent shapes i need the same two colour that i used for Educational Status

Comment: @VeeramaniNatarajan but since you're using colour to represent educational status won't that be confusing? It would imply some association between the two variables.

Comment: im learning R for past few weeks only. i know it confuses. but as im new, i dont had any idea to make it clear