# Assign stable colors to ggplot when reordering and subsetting

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, subset

In a shiny app, I let users subset data, and then create a plot in which a categorical variable is reordered from higher to lower according to the value of another variable and displayed following the user input.

I would like color and fill to be linked to the category variable *irrespective of the order*.

Tried and not working solutions:

- [How to assign colors to categorical variables in ggplot2 that have stable mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin#comment8263449_6924503)
- [How to manually set colours to a categorical variables using ggplot()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515024/how-to-manually-set-colours-to-a-categorical-variables-using-ggplot)

MWE:

```
data <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(rowname = reorder(rowname, mpg))

plot <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rowname, mpg, fill = rowname, color = rowname))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()

plot %+% droplevels(filter(data, rowid < 3))
```

produces this:

[image]

while

```
plot %+% droplevels(filter(data, rowid < 4))
```

produces this:

[image]

In a nutshell:

**Intended behavior**: colors are matched to category irrespective of order of the plot.

**Actual behavior**: colors change depending on position of the category once `reorder`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign a colour value to each category which you can use in `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual`.

```
values = c("Mazda RX4" = "red", "Mazda RX4 Wag" = "blue", "Datsun 710" = "green")
plot %+% droplevels(filter(data, rowid < 3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = values) +
  scale_color_manual(values = values)
plot %+% droplevels(filter(data, rowid < 4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = values) +
  scale_color_manual(values = values)
```

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

You can also do this automatically for all the levels.

```
library(scales)
values <- c(hue_pal()(length(levels(data$rowname))))
names(values) <- levels(data$rowname)
```

However, you'll have to think a bit more carefully about the colours when you have a large number of categories.